# Can I remove cpp from Ubuntu without causing any issues?

Tags: lamp, c++

I have a C++ compiler installed on a Ubuntu server I am using as a LAMP stack. Will it cause issues for me to remove C++?

Comment: Might I ask why you would want to remove it?  I doubt highly the extra few megabytes of data you get from removing the compiler is going to have a real impact on your system

Comment: I'm a fan of having the least number of programs installed as it (a) reduces the areas for hackers to exploit and (b) reduces the number of potential contributing factors to system issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have any issues with a server not having a compiler installed.

Normally a compiler does not belong to a LAMP server for security reasons. It "helps" an attacker to type in some code, compile it to a program, execute it and do a lot more damage.

A possible exception is if you have a device driver not part of the standard distro. Every time you update the kernel you would have to recompile that driver.